# Set up RubyMine2 to run and debug a Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rubymine

Can anyone provide setup instructions for running and debugging a sinatra app in Rubymine?

Comment: have you tried with version 3 eap?

Comment: in any case, rubymine has excellent support forums, which are much more suited for a question like this one.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if you found your answer on the JetBrains forum, but if not, here's what works for me in RubyMine 3.2.4.

My config.ru looks like:

```
require './app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

In a simple app.rb file, put a break point on the "Hello World" line below:

```
get '/' do
  "Hello World"
end
```

Just right-click on the app.rb or config.ru file, and select 'Debug "app"' from the context menu. You should hit your break point when you load the page.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

With the current RubyMine (5.4) you can run it by creating a Rack Run/Debug configuration and specifying path to your config.rb file in there.